# Роутер TP-Link меняет адрес в пакетах на свой. Как от этого избавиться?

Tags: linux, сервер, router, tp-link

Без использования роутера TP-Link WR740N вся система работает так:

[image: C[Схема сети]

Нужно получить доступ с сервера C к серверу A через сервер B. Настройки всех серверов я привел на изображении. Тестовый стенд готов, на сервере A запускаю программу tcpdump, а на сервере C выполняю команду ping 8.8.8.8. Все как и ожидалось: tcpdump показыват, что пакеты пришли с адреса 192.168.50.2. Все отлично.

Теперь я решил заменить сервер B роутером, о котором говорил выше. Все настройки сделал как у сервера B, к порту WAN подключил сервер A, к порту LAN1 сервер C. И снова, на сервере A запускаю tcpdump а на сервере C ping 8.8.8.8. В результате tcpdump показывает, что отправитель пакетов 172.20.0.2. Что не является ожидаемым для меня результатом.

Собственно вопрос. Каким образом можно настроить этот модем, чтобы результат получился схожим с сервером B? Я слышал, что на этот модем можно поставить OpenWRT. Поможет ли это настроить, если базовых настроек не хватит?

**UPD**
Если запустить команду ping 192.168.50.2 на сервере A, а на сервере C запустить tcpdump, то в качестве источника пакета будет указан адрес 172.20.0.1 (то есть не поменялся при прохождении через роутер)

Comment: тут скорее не базовых настроек нехватает а базовых знаний о том как работает роутер. настройте DMZ Zone на роутере для порта LAN1

Comment: Именно из-за нехватки знаний я и задал этот вопрос. Попробовал я настроить DMZ (в модеме только переключатель и строка адреса) но результат не поменялся. Как я понял из описания DMZ - это не совсем то, что мне нужно.

Comment: Может нужен другой роутер?

Comment: Может быть. Но задача в том, чтобы настроить имеющийся роутер, если это конечно возможно.
Возможно нужно настроить роутер в режиме Bridge? я так понимаю, это уже ближе к моей задаче?

Comment: Нет, в режиме Bridge, роутер просто соединяет wan и выбранный порт lan в одну сеть. Не подходит такой вариант.

Comment: DMZ ничего не даст, требуется режим роутера без NAT, но не все железяки его поддерживают. Если на железке есть доступ по телнет или SSH, можно вручную отключить NAT, и настроить маршруты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Требуется роутер уровня SOHO, никак не домашний. Минимальное по деньгам, что вполне реально настроить нужным образом - из любимых лично мной микротиков - Mikrotik Hap Lite, на момент публикации стоит от 1500 рублей.

Есть вариант экспериментов с прошивкой dd-wrt, OpenWrt, шанс очень большой, что всё там заработает, но проблема - текущих знаний может не хватить для настройки. К сожалению, у меня такого образчика нет, не смогу сказать, что лучше.

Суть проблемы в механизме NAT. Сервер А и С находятся в разных подсетях, поэтому напрямую они не смогут общаться между собой, им для общения требуется железяка, которая умеет маршрутизировать (домашний "роутер" умеет только NATить), порты которой находятся в обоих подсетях, маршруты в сети А и С прописаны на серверах А и С, либо просто ип адрес порта роутера В указан в качестве шлюза по умолчанию.

Наглядная документация по теме NAT есть в гугле по запросу "сети для самых маленьких", там же и про маршрутизацию немного.

Answer (score 0):

От SOHO роутера вы желаемого поведения я думаю не добьетесь. Так как они как правило работают в режиме NAT (это как раз тот случай когда у вас подменяются адреса) иногда бывает поддержка режима Bridge но как вы написали в комментариях он вам не подходит так как объединяет все в одну сеть.

Для того чтобы добиться того результата который вы хотите (если я вас правильно понял) вам нужно:

1. Прописать на 2 интерфейсах разные сети (возможно в режиме Bridge это все-таки можно сделать).
2. Сразу после этого трафик может не пойти так как возможно понадобиться включить роутениг, то есть разрешить роутеру перебрасывать пакеты с одного интерфейса на другой.

Возможно это можно будет сделать после прошивки в OpenWRT, впрочем не имея железки на руках не могу точнее подсказать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Судя по тому, что я знаю о NAT - из внешней сети не видны компьютеры, расположенные за NAT (возможен только проброс портов). В моем же случае все компьютеры видят друг друга. Но в одну сторону пакеты отправляются с подменой (почему-то поведение как при включенном NAT), а в другую сторону подмена не происходит (т.к. пакет доходит без проблем до внутреннего IP. Стоит полагать, что NAT отсутствует). Я это дописал в разделе UPD первого сообщения.

Comment: Чтобы не гадать неплохо было бы посмотреть как именно настроен роутер. У вас в обще стороны пакеты проходят по конечным адресам? То есть с сервера А: ping 192.168.50.2, а сервера C: ping 172.20.0.1?

Comment: Я утром скину все настройки. А так да. Пинг идет в обе стороны. С сервера A на сервер C пинг пошел после добавления статического роута на сервере A "route add -net 192.168.50.0/24 gw 172.20.0.1 dev eth0" (Вроде так. Утром проверю.)

Comment: Мне уже начинает казаться, что это какой-то баг в роутере. Проверил версию прошивки на сайте производителя, но не обнаружил новее.