# Port Forwarding - переадресация порта

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, port

Я уже задавал тему с почти подобным вопросом но к конечной точки так и не пришел, даже после прочтение литературы.

Наши устройства:

1. Ноутбук с ip адресом 192.168.0.24 подключен к switch
2. Первая линукс машина:

`eth1` с ip адресом `192.168.0.155` - подключено к switch

`auto eth1
iface ethic net dhcp`

`iptables` выглядит так:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE`

и

`eth0` с ip адресом `192.168.2.155` - подключена к eth0 второй линукс машины.

`auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.155
netmask 255.255.255.0`

3. Вторая линукс машина:

`eth0` с  ip адресом `192.168.2.167` - подключена к `eth0` первой линукс машины и имеет доступ в сеть через нее.

`auto eth0
iface ethic net dhcp`

---

Мне нужно добавить правило в `iptables` первой линукс машины, чтобы при подсоединении с помощью ноутбука через `ssh root@192.168.0.155 -73`или любой другой порт, это не главное, меня перекидывало на `ssh` подключение второй линукс машины.

Comment: 192.168. **0** .155?

Comment: @PavelMayorov не понял вас

Comment: Третий октет у вас точно 0? Выше по тексту используется 2.

Comment: Конфигурация сети не ясна, каша. [Вот как правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461368/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-tp-link-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)

Comment: @PavelMayorov точно. Ноутбук и первая линукс машина через `eth1` подключены к xxx.xxx.0.xxx сети, а уже первая линукс машина создает свою сеть и раздает интернет через `eth0` второй линукс машине.

Comment: @dnsk что вам не понятно?

Comment: @Insider ЭВМ1(eth0 - ip1, eth1 - ip2 ), ЭВМ2(... итд. без нормально описанной конфигурации сети, тут буду гадания, а не поиск решения.

Comment: А ещё сам ssh может свои туннели рыть. Может такой путь будет проще iptables, тем более если нужен только ssh

Comment: нужен не только ssh. @PavelMayorov после долгих "стараний", так и не нашел способ, как выйти через вторую машину в интернет. не пускает.

Comment: @Insider задавайте отдельный вопрос. Никто не будет вам объяснять как настроить маршрутизацию в вопросе о порт форвардинге.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.155 --dport 73 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.167:22
```

Comment: ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.155 port 73: Connection refused

Comment: iptables -L -n ???

Comment: @dsnk `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination  `

Comment: С первой машины вторая вообще пингуется?

Comment: @PavelMayorov да.

Comment: @Insider а интернет - со второй машины виден?

Comment: @PavelMayorov ping www.google.com - неудачен, ping 192.168.0.155 - неудачен, ping 192.168.2.155 - полет нормальный.

Comment: @Insider ну так с этого и надо было начинать! Вы же писали, что "вторая машина имеет доступ в сеть через первую" - но на самом деле это не так. Как настроите базовый доступ в сеть - так и порт форвардингом можно будет заняться.

Comment: @PavelMayorov настройка происходит также через iptables? Если да, могли бы вы мне помочь?

Comment: @Insider задайте отдельный вопрос, а потом вернетесь к этому. Или лучше погуглите - проблема-то простая и частая.

Comment: @PavelMayorov так ведь базовые настройки настроены, если я вас правильно понял, `gateway` и ip адреса в порядке.