# Маршрутизация между двумя сетями и машинами

Tags: linux, сеть

Отдельный вопрос [темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461591/port-forwarding-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0?noredirect=1#comment505913_461591)

Нужно настроить маршрутизацию между двумя локальными сетями и машинами:

С первой машины `192.168.0.24` - я могу отпинговать вторую `eth1: 192.168.0.155`. Если зайти через SSH на вторую машину `eth1: 192.168.0.155`; пинается третья машина `eth0: 192.168.2.167`. Также и наоборот, но с первой машины не пингуется последняя - `eth0: 192.168.2.167`

---

Выглядит на схеме вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что мои правила в `iptables` не запускались автоматически. после проверки `iptables -t nat -L` это удалось выяснить и уже установить все остальное.

Answer (score 0):

На 192.168.0.155 нужно объединить оба сетевых интерфейса в bridge, либо напрямую подключить 192.168.2.167 к роутеру.

Comment: Правильные ли эти настройки [Картинка](http://prntscr.com/8w7vch)  ?

Comment: На 192.168.2.167 надо шлюз прописать 192.168.0.1
А на том компе где две сетевухи, объединить их в мост

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне написать, как правильно соединить их при помощи `/etc/network/interfaces` а не скриптов?

Comment: Не-а, вот что смог быстро ответить. Сейчас сильно загружен задачами. При желание вы можете погуглить, по этой теме много информации.

Answer (score 0):

На маршрутизаторе можно добавить маршрут

192.168.2.255/24 через 192.168.0.155

Comment: маршрут через роутер мне не подходит.

Comment: И включить маршрутизацию на 192.168.0.155. А то обычно отключена

Comment: Тогда на самом 192.168.0.24 пропиши этот маршрут

Comment: @Insider Если маршрут через роутер не подходит, то вышеуказанный маршрут следует прописать на всех узлах подсети 192.168.0.0/24, которым требуется доступ к 192.168.2.0/24, сделать это можно как вручную, так и с помощью DHCP.

Comment: @dsnk мои знания о сети, поверхностны, не могли бы вы написать как именно? На машине 192.168.0.155 сейчас такие настройки http://prntscr.com/8w7vch

Comment: Отчего маршрутизация на роутере не подходит? Все равно же трафик через него идёт, если конечно router и switch - одно лицо

Comment: @banme от того, что при переносе всей схемы кроме роутера в другую квартиру/дом и тд, нужно будет опять настраивать роутер. А так я подключил и все работает.

Comment: @banme Иногда роутеры не в состоянии на большой скорости пробрасывать трафик, т.к. внутри он идёт через процессор.

Comment: @Insider на машине 192.168.0.1 выполните команду `route add -net 192.168.2.0/24 gw 192.168.0.155`

Comment: @dsnk Машина 192.168.0.1 - это обычный свитч или роутер.

Comment: @Insider не обратил внимания на надпись GW, тогда на машине `192.168.0.24`

Comment: @dsnk видите ли в чем проблема, вся конфигурация должна происходить на `192.168.0.155`, не могу ведь я постоянно отдавать мой ноутбук - `192.168.0.24` другим

Comment: @Insider дело в том, что к вашей машине пакеты дорогу найдут, а вот обратно куда идти им не указано, значит они будут отправляться на шлюз `192.168.0.1`, поэтому маршрут надо прописать либо на вашей машине, либо на шлюзе.

Comment: Чего хотите добиться конкретно? Там нельзя конфигурацию править, сям нельзя... Поставить dhcp-сервер на 192.168.0.155 можно? В одну и другую сетку пусть раздаёт соответствующие адреса и маршруты

Comment: @banme смысл в том, чтобы вторая машина `192.168.0.155` раздавала сеть третьей `192.168.2.167`, для этого разные интерфейсы. Обе машины должны быть доступны с любого компьютера в моем примере это `192.168.0.24`, не полагаясь на настройки роутера

Comment: Кто-то должен сообщить любому компьютеру как достичь сегмента 192.168.2.0. Либо вручную заколачивать на всех любых машинах, либо один раз на роутере. Ещё можно посмотреть тему динамической маршрутизации - какой-нибудь самый примитивный активировать. Ещё всякие проски/туннели во второй сегмент для конкретных задач

Comment: @banme как достичь `192.168.2.0` говорит `iptables`. Но вот выйти с помощью `192.168.2.0` сети в интернет не получается. Загвоздка только в этом.

Comment: Кому он говорит? А выйти 192.168.2.0 в интернет в Вашей ситуации поможет как раз тот же iptables. На 192.168.0.155 сделайте NAT для сегмента 192.168.2.0 (если не хотите трогать роутер 192.168.0.1)

Comment: @banme в `iptables` уже есть настройки `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE` но я не могу отпинговать из сети `192.168.2.0` мой ноутбук - `192.168.0.24`, а все потому что, меня не выпускает из первой машины.

Comment: @banme Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30816/discussion-between-insider-and-banme).